# Man on a rotating platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, inertial-frames, coriolis-effect

> A platform rotates in counterclockwise with angular velocity w. A man
>   walks from the center of the platform to the border with constant
>   radial velocity v' wrt the platform. $\mu_s$ is the static friction
>   coefficient.
>
> Calculate the minimum value for $\mu_s$ such that the radial motion is
>   straight. What about a', value of the man acceleration wrt the
>   platform?

I know that $a_0=a'+a_{cc}+a_c$ where:

$a_0$ absolute acceleration, a'=man acceleration wrt the patform, $a_{cc}= 2 w \times v'$, $a_c=-w^2 r u_r$

$u_r$= unit vector with radial direction
$u_t$= unit vector with tangent direction

I have calculated:

absolute velocity : $v_0=v' u_r+wr w_t$

absolute acceleration: $dv_0/dt=2v' w u_t-w^2r u_r$

I want that the man goes straight on respect with an observer on the paltform, so I "cancel" the Coriolis acceleration:
$\mu_s =2v'w/g$

$a'=a_0-a_{cc}-a_c+a_{friction}=2v'wu_t$

But I have obtained the Coriolis acceleration! ... Something went wrong. I thing that maybe there is a conceptuar error.. Please, help me!

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie Please read again the question. I don't want the solution. "they have a reason to believe they have made a mistake at all" (in the discussion you posted): it's exactly my case. I'd like to know if what I did (that isn't the solution to the exercise, of course) is conceptually wrong (very likely to me) or not.

Comment: Calculate centripetal force needed to keep the man rotating at any $r$, at $\omega$. This force needs to be provided by friction. Calculate minimum $\mu_s$ for maximum $r$. Assuming no radial acceleration, the man's acceleration is simply the centripetal acceleration.

Comment: @Gert and what about Coriolis force? it makes steer the trajectory....

Comment: "constant radial velocity v' **with respect to** the platform" (please don't use acronyms). Coriolis doesn't come into it. The **rotating** platform is your reference frame. I'm voting to close this now.

Comment: Say you paint a straight line from centre to rim on the platform. Now the man needs to walk that line and that requires friction. Viewed from above his trajectory is a spiral of course.

Comment: @Gert I'm sorry, I haven't understood why I don't have to consider the Coriolis force. Man velocity with respect to the platform isn't zero and the platform is rotating. So I have to consider Coriolis acceleration, because Coriolis acceleration makes steer the trajectory but the trajectory has to be straight... thanks for the help

Comment: The Coriolis force is a *fictitious* force that explains the spirally trajectory observed from a *bird's eye' perspective. Seen from the centre of the platform the man walks in a straight line (provided there's enough friction). In that reference frame (which is what the question is about) and assuming the radial (man) and angular (platform) speed is constant the only two forces acting (and cancelling) on the man is centripetal force and counter-acting friction. No net force means linear uniform motion in that frame of reference.

Comment: @Gert  I find some aspects of rotational motion difficult to visualise.If the man is at a certain position on his radial line and then moves further out his tangential velocity increases.  What causes that increase in tangential velocity?